# Order by is currently only supported on the clustered columns of the PRIMARY KEY

Tags: cassandra, sql-order-by, cql

cassandra2.0.7  cql 3.1.1

```
CREATE TABLE playlists (
  id uuid,
  song_order int,
  song_id uuid,
  title text,
  album text,
  artist text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id, song_order ) );


INSERT INTO playlists (id, song_order, song_id, title, artist, album)
  VALUES (62c36092-82a1-3a00-93d1-46196ee77204, 1,
  a3e64f8f-bd44-4f28-b8d9-6938726e34d4, 'La Grange', 'ZZ Top', 'Tres Hombres');

INSERT INTO playlists (id, song_order, song_id, title, artist, album)
  VALUES (62c36092-82a1-3a00-93d1-46196ee77204, 2,
  8a172618-b121-4136-bb10-f665cfc469eb, 'Moving in Stereo', 'Fu Manchu', 'We Must Obey');

INSERT INTO playlists (id, song_order, song_id, title, artist, album)
  VALUES (62c36092-82a1-3a00-93d1-46196ee77204, 3,
  2b09185b-fb5a-4734-9b56-49077de9edbf, 'Outside Woman Blues', 'Back Door Slam', 'Roll Away');


  SELECT * FROM playlists WHERE id = 62c36092-82a1-3a00-93d1-46196ee77204  
  ORDER BY song_order DESC LIMIT 2;

error: Order by is currently only supported on the clustered columns
   of the PRIMARY KEY, got song_order
```

this demo from :  http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html

who can tell me why ?
thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you created the table properly? I've just tried on the latest 2.x branch and all worked fine. Double check your primary key, if you misplaced a closing bracket then you might have a composite partition key ((id, song_order )) instead of ((id), song_order)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this when you create your table.

```
CREATE TABLE playlists ( 
    id uuid, song_order int, song_id uuid, title text, album text, artist text, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id, song_order)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (song_order ASC);
```

Comment: Yes that will work, but it doesn't answer his question of "why?"

Comment: The reason why it will work is that you are telling Cassandra to store the clustering key in order when the data is written to the SSTables.  Otherwise, ordering it not guaranteed and the query in Cassandra would be very inefficient.