# Cassandra - Grouping By ID and Ordering by Date

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, data-modeling, cql

A portion of my application consists of a discussion board: there are threads, posts, and categories. Threads are grouped by category, and posts are grouped by threads. I'm having a problem coming up with a model / query that will allow the selection threads by category with a descending ordering of their last post.

Category

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.categories (
    id ascii PRIMARY KEY,
    description text,
    name text,
    ...
);
```

Thread

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.threads (
    id ascii PRIMARY KEY,
    category_id ascii,
    content text,
    ...
);
```

Post

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.posts (
    thread_id ascii,
    created_at timestamp,
    id ascii,
    content text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (thread_id, created_at, id)
);
```

I initially thought about putting the last post's "created at" time as a clustering key on the thread table, but that's impossible as it changes with each post.

I then thought about creating an intermediate table that is written to every time a post is created. This solves the immutability issue with the first approach, but the problem is that it will contain multiple values per thread and I have not been able to figure out a partition / clustering order that would support grouping by thread and ordering by date.

For example, the following would allow me to group by thread, but not order by date:

```
CREATE TABLE last_post_for_category (
    category_id ascii,
    thread_id ascii,
    created_at timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((category_id), thread_id, created_at)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (thread_id DESC, created_at DESC);

SELECT thread_id FROM last_post_for_category WHERE category_id = 'category' GROUP BY thread_id, created_at;
```

And the following would allow me to order by date, but not group by thread:

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.last_post_for_category (
    category_id ascii,
    thread_id ascii,
    created_at timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((category_id), created_at, thread_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC, thread_id DESC);

SELECT thread_id FROM last_post_for_category WHERE category_id = 'category' GROUP BY created_at, thread_id;
```

I'm not able to do a `distinct` on `(category_id, thread_id)` either as I know nothing about thread IDs at the point in which this query is executed.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can best represent this ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend that you use the datatype `datetime` rather than `timestamp`, since it will make it easy for you to modify it or set a default value. This is just a recommendation.

**Suggested solution:**

Add the attribute `last_post` to the table `threads` to save the time of last added post in each thread.
When a thread is first created, the `last_post` value should equal a very old date (because no posts in that thread yet).

After tha, create a trigger so that whenever a post is inserted in `posts`, the trigger updates the `last_post` value of the corresponding thread. The trigger can be added like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerName ON posts
FOR INSERT
AS
declare @post_time datetime;
declare @thread_id int;
select @post_time=i.created_at from inserted i;
select @thread_id=i.thread_id from inserted i;

update threads set lastpost = @post_time where id=@thread_id  
GO
```

Last step will be a direct query to select threads by category sorted by `last_post`, just like this:

```
select * from threads where category_id = 'theCategoryYouWant' order by lastpost asc /*or desc as you like*/
```

**Note:** if you want `created_at` to be updated when the post is edited, you will need to add a similar trigger to update the `last_post` attribute of the corresponding thread.

Comment: Since I can't make last_post a clustering key, I tried creating an index and ordering on that, but I'm not able to do so:

`InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Order by is currently only supported on the clustered columns of the PRIMARY KEY, got last_post"`

Comment: Why can't you make it the key? Did not the deduced query at the end of my answer solve your problem ?!

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802443/order-by-is-currently-only-supported-on-the-clustered-columns-of-the-primary-key

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but I can’t make it a key as Cassandra doesn’t let you mutate them. When I first tried to solve this, I ended up having to delete and recreate rows with the updated date.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong. `last_post` is just a `datetime` attribute. Nothing is special about it. You don't have to make it a primary nor a secondary key. Just update it through the trigger whenever a new post is added. Please give me more information about your problem with that. I mean, why you cannot mutate it although it is a regular attribute and nothing special about it ?! Why you can mutate other attributes but not `last_post` specifically ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I said it's immutable because I have been unable thus far to order by a field that isn't a clustering key, even with a secondary or sasi index.